# Angular2 plugin for SonarQube 6.x

Tags: angular, sonarqube

I am new with Sonar and I have recently installed SonarQube 6.3
I couldnt find any plugin for AngularJS neither Angular2.

Is there any way to have an Angular scanner? Any plans to release one for SonarQube 6.X?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are plenty of plugins on GitHub.

For example:

- [sonar-web-frontend-plugin](https://github.com/groupe-sii/sonar-web-frontend-plugin) for many front end technologies including AngularJS and TypeScript but is a bit old. It analyzes the scanners' reports.
- [SonarTsPlugin](https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin) for TypeScript and so Angular 2. It directly performs an analysis.
- [SonarTS](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarTS) is the official SonarSource plugin for TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks! :-)
I thougth there was no one, as i havent seen any at the update center settings tab

Comment: There is now the official SonarQube plugin for TS.

Comment: SonarTs (which is the same as the plugin) will check TypeScript rules but will not detect Angular anti-patterns.